# grab the current index of the element from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an image array like this

```
var bigImagesList = document.getElementsByClassName('monique-image');
```

Now i am trying to check if an image in an array is having current path like tis

```
for (var i = 0; i < bigImagesList.length; i++) {

    if (bigImagesList[i].getAttribute('src') === currentBigImageFilePath) {

        // Current Image Big Grab //
        currentBigImageToDisplay = bigImagesList[i];
        var currentIndex = bigImagesList[i].index;
        console.log(currentIndex);
```

but somehow it says **undefined** . Please tell me how can i grab the index of the current item in if condition. thanks

Comment: I feel that `i` is the `currentIndex`?

Comment: @Praveen can you tell me how to log that?

Comment: Er... `Console.log(i)`?

Comment: console.log(i) gives me the whole element back...,

Comment: @Praveen yes now it does.

Comment: The `i` just holds a number.

Comment: Answer it and let me check it .  thankssss!

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are looping through the array, already you have the index there, as you are looping through the array of `bigImagesList`. So you might just need to replace:

```
var currentIndex = bigImagesList[i].index;
```

With:

```
var currentIndex = i;
```

You don't even need to create a new variable, IMO.

Comment: @Thankssssssssssssssssss

Comment: Now if i have to add one to it like 0 index should be 1 and 1 should be 2  so i add 1+ i; but it somehow concatenates instead of adding .. :(

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini That’s because `i` is a string, like all object properties. Convert it to a number.

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini You can convert it to a number using `parseInt(i)`.